# ElasticSearch search email by full match

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to search contacts by email. According to [ES documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-uaxurlemail-tokenizer.html) the best way to achieve that is using `uax_url_email` tokenizer. Here is my index settings:

```
settings: {
  index: {
    creation_date: "1467895098804",
    analysis: {
      analyzer: {
        email: {
          type: "custom",
          tokenizer: "uax_url_email"
        }
      }
    },
    number_of_shards: "5",
    number_of_replicas: "1",
    uuid: "wL0P6OIaQqqYpFDvIHArTw",
    version: {
      created: "2030399"
    }
  }
}
```

and mapping:

```
contact: {
  dynamic: "false",
  properties: {
    contact_status: {
      type: "string"
    },
    created_at: {
      type: "date",
      format: "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
    },
    email: {
      type: "string"
    },
    id: {
      type: "long"
    },
    mailing_ids: {
      type: "long"
    },
    subscription_status: {
      type: "string"
    },
    type_ids: {
      type: "long"
    },
    updated_at: {
      type: "date",
      format: "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
    },
    user_id: {
      type: "long"
    }
  }
}
```

After creating index I've inserted two documents:

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/contacts/contact/1' -d '{"contact_status": "confirmed", "email": "example@gmail.com", "id": "1", "user_id": "1", "subscription_status": "on"}'
```

and

```
curl -X PUT 'localhost:9200/contacts/contact/2' -d '{"contact_status": "confirmed", "email": "example@yahoo.com", "id": "2", "user_id": "2", "subscription_status": "on"}'
```

Then I'm trying to search contacts by email in different ways:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/contacts/_search?pretty' -d '{"query": {"bool": {"must": [ {"match": {"_all": { "query": "example@google.com", "analyzer": "email" } } } ] } } }'
```

I expected to get 1 result with id=1, but got empty hits:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

The next search query I've tested was:

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/contacts/_search?pretty' -d '{"query": {"bool": {"must": [ {"match": {"_all": { "query": "example@google", "analyzer": "email" } } } ] } } }'
```

which returned 2 results:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 0.016878016,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "contacts",
      "_type" : "contact",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 0.016878016,
      "_source" : {
        "contact_status" : "confirmed",
        "email" : "example@yahoo.com",
        "id" : "2",
        "user_id" : "2",
        "subscription_status" : "on"
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "contacts",
      "_type" : "contact",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.016878016,
      "_source" : {
        "contact_status" : "confirmed",
        "email" : "example@gmail.com",
        "id" : "1",
        "user_id" : "1",
        "subscription_status" : "on"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

But as you understand I expected to get 1 document in search result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `email` only contains the email address why don't you make that field `"index":"not_analyzed"` and then use a `term` filter to search for the email address?

Comment: Because I also need to search by user_id, id and other fields. More over I want to search by part of email, like this:    type `example` in input and get list of emails which contains 'example', in my case - both documents. Or if  I type `gmail.com` => get document with id 1

Comment: I suggest this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115867/elasticsearch-analyzer-and-tokenizer-for-emails If you have any difficulties or a different use case than that one let me know.

Answer (score 14):

Use this to make your request  It work for me

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase_prefix" : {
            "email": "valery@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

You will have the expecting result

Answer (score 8):

This is what happened:

The "`uax_url_email`" tokenizer is equal to the 'standard" tokenizer (meaning it cuts out "@") except when it gets a pattern of `"<text>@<text>.<text>"` in which case it doesn't cut the "@" but takes the **whole** email address as one token.

Now, at *index time* you defined "email" field as "string" which defaults to "standard" tokenizer, meaning - your address was tokenized into **2** tokens: "`example`" and "`gmail.com`"! At *search time* you defined "email" tokenizer, meaning, your (first) query "example@google.com" wasn't tokenized at all (since it falles into an email pattern) so it didn't match neither "example" or "gmail.com" (and same for yahoo).
In your second query you searched for "example@google" - this doesn't fall into a whole email pattern so the email tokenizer worked as the "standard" tokenizer meaning it cuts the "@" and tokenize "example" and "google" looking for either one in your index. Since example is indexed in your 2 documents - it fits both!

If you want to be able to match only the "example" part of your address - you can't use your "email" analyzer at search time! ***In any case, most of the time, you shouldn't change your search analyzer from your index analyzer***!

Mind that the "standard" analyzer won't cut "gmail.com" into 2 tokens!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I thought specifying analyzer in search query analyzes properties, instead of search query. :( So as I understand I should specify analyzer for email at 'create index' stage. The problem is that I already have such index scheme on production with 600k+ documents in it and the only way to fix this search issue is recreating this index?

Comment: You should specify your "email" analyzer in the mapping. That way, every new document will be analyzed with it. In order to do that you only need to create a new index with the new mapping and reindex your old index to the new one. It's very easy. And again, You will only be able to match the email as a whole!

Answer (score 0):

I used

```json
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "email": {
        "value": "example@gmail.com",
        "flags": "NONE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/regexp-syntax.html