# Multifield wildcard search in ElasticSearch

Tags: t-sql, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Consider this very basic T-SQL query:

```
select * from Users
where FirstName like '%dm0e776467@mail.com%' 
or LastName like '%dm0e776467@mail.com%' 
or Email like '%dm0e776467@mail.com%'
```

How can I write this in Lucene?

I have tried the following:

1. The query way (does not work at all, no results):

   {
   "query": {
   "bool": {
   "should": [
   {
   "wildcard": {
   "firstName": "*dm0e776467@mail.com*"
   }
   },
   {
   "wildcard": {
   "lastName": "*dm0e776467@mail.com*"
   }
   },
   {
   "wildcard": {
   "email": "*dm0e776467@mail.com*"
   }
   }
   ]
   }
   }
   }
2. The Multimatch way (returns anything where mail.com is present)

   {
   "query": {
   "multi_match": {
   "query": "dm0e776467@mail.com",
   "fields": [
   "firstName",
   "lastName",
   "email"
   ]
   }
   }
   }
3. A third attempt (returns expected result, but if I only insert "mail", then no results are returned)

   {
   "query": {
   "query_string": {
   "query": ""dm0e776467@mail.com"",
   "fields": [
   "firstName",
   "lastName",
   "email"
   ],
   "default_operator": "or",
   "allow_leading_wildcard": true
   }
   }
   }

It seems to me as there is no way to force Elasticsearch to force a query to use the input string as **ONE** substring?

Answer (score 1):

The [`standard`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) (default) analyzer will tokenize this email as follows:

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": "dm0e776467@mail.com",
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

yielding

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "dm0e776467",
      ...
    },
    {
      "token" : "mail.com",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

This explains why the multi-match works with any `*mail.com` suffix and why the wildcards are failing.

---

I suggest the following modifications to your mapping, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30116612/8160318):

```
PUT users
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "email": {
          "type": "pattern_capture",
          "preserve_original": true,
          "patterns": [
            "([^@]+)",
            "(\\p{L}+)",
            "(\\d+)",
            "@(.+)",
            "([^-@]+)"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "email": {
          "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
          "filter": [
            "email",
            "lowercase",
            "unique"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "email": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "email"
      },
      "firstName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "as_email": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "email"
          }
        }
      },
      "lastName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "as_email": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "email"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I've used `.as_email` fields on your `first-` & `lastName` fields -- you may not want to force them to be mapped as emails by default.

Then after indexing a few samples:

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"users","_type":"_doc"}}
{"firstName":"abc","lastName":"adm0e776467@mail.coms","email":"dm0e776467@mail.com"}
{"index":{"_index":"users","_type":"_doc"}}
{"firstName":"xyz","lastName":"opr","email":"dm0e776467@mail.com"}
{"index":{"_index":"users","_type":"_doc"}}
{"firstName":"zyx","lastName":"dm0e776467@mail.com","email":"qwe"}
{"index":{"_index":"users","_type":"_doc"}}
{"firstName":"abc","lastName":"efg","email":"ijk"}
```

the wildcards are working perfectly fine:

```
GET users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "email": "dm0e776467@mail.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "lastName.as_email": "dm0e776467@mail.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "firstName.as_email": "dm0e776467@mail.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Do check how this tokenizer works under the hood to prevent 'surprising' query results:

```
GET users/_analyze
{
  "text": "dm0e776467@mail.com",
  "field": "email"
}
```